# Virtual addresses: multiple of four aligned - writing to address "in between"

Tags: c, paging, memory-address, virtual-memory

When executing some programs I realized that virtual addresses are always multiples of four (assuming 32 Bit Virtual Addresses). Example:

```
int main()
{
   int a = 7;
   int b = 10;
   printf("%p %p", &a, &b);
}
```

will give something like:

- xff86c930 0xff86c934
- xfff58f80 0xfff58f84
- ...

The difference between them is always four.
Now I tried this:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 7; 
    int b = 10;
    int *y = &b;
    int yi = (int)y;
    yi--;
    y = (int*)yi;
    printf("%p %p: %d\n", &b, y, *y);
    *y = 7;
    printf("%p: %d\n", y, *y);
}
```

One example output is:

0xffe460a0 0xffe4609f: 2807

0xffe4609f: 7

What's going on here? What is referenced when I try to write something to an address which is not a multiple of four? Where does this 2807 come from? Will there be a pagefault?

Comment: `virtual addresses are always multiples of four` it is not true

Comment: This is called Undefined Behaviour. You have manipulated `y` to become an invalid pointer.

Comment: @Lashane assuming this architecture, it is...I will add this to my question.

Comment: @kaylum Is there a pagefault occuring?

Comment: @今天春天 even if we assume this architecture - it is not true

Comment: Can you correct my statement, please?

Comment: every byte in virtual memory has its own address, distance between addresses - 1 byte, so you have some valid pointer to 4 byte data and shifted it to the left, so now it points to different 4 bytes

Comment: There is no point explaining Undefined Behaviour. To explain exactly what happens would require analysis of the assembly and the memory layout. Both of which can change depending on the OS, the source code, the compiler used, the compiler flags used, the loader, the kernel, etc. And that is all dependent on your environment and not something anyone else can easily reproduce straight off. It's not a productive exercise.

Comment: There is not "nothing" between your integers if `sizeof(int) == 4` on your system (which is highly likely). But even if you repeat your experiment with smaller variables - say, `char`, you may OR may not find that your compiler stores them at 4-byte intervals. It's just usually a very convenient way of storing data. (On some systems it is even the ONLY way.)

Comment: So it sounds like you know you've deliberately constructed a more-or-less invalid pointer value in `y`.  It sounds like you know that dereferencing this pointer value might have unexpected or unusual results, perhaps even a page fault.  It sounds like when you tried it, the unusual result you got was 2807.  So what are you asking?  Are you asking "Why did I not get a page fault?"  Are you asking "Why did I get 2807 and not 41175349?"

Comment: Really, the only answer is: you did something dangerous which would be expected to give an unexpected value; when you tried it you did indeed get an unexpected value, ergo → universe working as expected!

Comment: Your question is sort of like, "I know it's dangerous, but last night I drank a bunch of whiskey and got in my car blindfolded and put it in reverse and floored it.  I ended up in a ditch with a guardrail through the rear window of the car.  It almost took my head off.  Where did that guardrail come from?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take y as an int (dangerous on 64-bit systems)

```
int yi = (int)y;
```

Decrement its address as an integer and not a pointer - will cause it to become unaligned.

```
yi--;
```

Hard code that new integer back as a pointer - this pointer is now probably very dangerous to use

```
y = (int*)yi;
```

Dereference the unaligned pointer.  This will do different things on different systems depending on the memory controller.  At best, it seg-faults immediately so that you make no assumptions.

```
printf("%p %p: %d\n", &b, y, *y);
```

Stomp some more on unaligned memory for fun - why not.

```
*y = 7;
```

Where does 2807 come from?  It is whatever the memory controller wants to give you.  Perhaps it is the garbage value earlier in the stack, perhaps it is a barrel shifted value of the word below, it is completely the system's choice.

This is what @kaylum meant with his UB comment.

Comment: @Michael, why is it required for memory to be aligned with 32 bytes (on 32 bit processor) , why there is this limit .... my doubt is processor does not read 32 bit  at a time  , it read a cache line block , so why there is 32 bit alignment required?? it should be dependent on cache line  alignment.